# Effect on gravitational potential due to gravitational time dilation

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation

Are there any changes that happen in gravitational potential due to gravitational time dilation ?

For example a planet is moving (orbiting) very close to a star, so will there be any deviation of the orbit due to time dilation caused by such a huge gravity?

Answer (score 2):

The time dilation doesn’t cause the gravitational potential and thus doesn’t affect it; instead it is the potential that causes the dilation. Or at least this is a common way to look at it in the Newtonian approximation to General Relativity. You could also argue that neither causes the other but they are simply related to each other. In any case, the dilation doesn’t change the potential. The relevant geodesic equation for the orbit takes both the potential and the time dilation into account.